# How can I tell if a browser is using ssl false start?

Tags: ssl, https

In early 2011, Google implemented [SSL False Start](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/ssl-falsestart-performance-results.html) in the Chrome browser. From what I've read, it was compatible with almost every HTTPS website. Just to be sure (and out of curiosity) I'd like to test my webserver to ensure that it's working correctly with false start. How can I diagnose this? I believe that I can turn off false start in Chrome via the [-disable-ssl-false-start](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=78840a24f4ed266a&hl=en) flag. And I suspect that I could use a proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to intercept the SSL session and check explicitly. Or maybe look at the TCP stream directly with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)? But those all seem like very complicated approaches. Is there a better way?